# Extent S4 class, how to use superclass' constructor

Tags: r, r-s4

In my package, I want to subclass a class `TheBaseClass` from a contributed package (so it is out of my reach). There is a function for creating objects of this class. Here is a minimal example for that code.

```
setClass("TheBaseClass", representation(a="numeric"))
initBase <- function() new("TheBaseClass", a=1)  # in reality more complex
```

Now I want simply use `initBase` as constructor for my subclass, but I do not know how
to set the new class

```
setClass("MyInheritedClass", contains="TheBaseClass")
initInher <- function() {
    res <- initBase()
    class(res) <- "MyInheritedClass" # this does not work for S4
}
```

How can I alter the last line to make it work? Copy & paste the `initBase` function is not an option, since it involves a `.C` call. I read about `setIs`, but this seems not to be the right function here.

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247583/inheritance-in-r/16248773#16248773) provides more extensive explanation. One pattern is to provide an instance of the base class as an unnamed argument to your class constructor

```
.MyInheritedClass <- setClass("MyInheritedClass", contains="TheBaseClass")
.MyInheritedClass(initBase())
```

(`setClass` returns a generator function, which is really no different from calling `new` but seems cleaner; I use `.` in front, because generators are maybe a little too crude for "end users", e.g., there is no hint about what the arguments are supposed to be, just `...`). This assumes that you have not written an initialize method for your class, or that your initialize method has been constructed in a way that is consistent with the contract of initialize,ANY-method, with a slightly more complicated class

```
.A <- setClass("A", contains="TheBaseClass",
    representation=representation(x="numeric"))

setMethod(initialize, "A",
   function(.Object, ..., x)
{
    x <- log(x)                          # your class-specific initialization...
    callNextMethod(.Object, ..., x = x)  # passed to parent constructor
})
```

This pattern requires that the initialize method of the base class has been designed correctly. In action:

```
> .A(initBase(), x=1:2)
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472

Slot "a":
numeric(0)
```

Comment: this is really helpful; also the answer you linked to, which I did not find before. Thanks!