# How to define an S4 prototype for inherited slots

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I have a base class (let's call it "A") whose representation is common to many other classes.

Therefore I define other classes, such as "B", to contain this class.

I would like to set the prototype of these other classes (B) to include the default values for the slots inherited from A.  I thought this would be natural:

```
setClass("A", representation(a="character"))
setClass("B", contains="A", prototype(a = "hello"))
```

But it produces the error:

```
Error in representation[!slots] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Not sure why this happens.  If I omit the prototype I can do:

```
setClass("B", contains="A")
```

and then hack my own generator function:

```
new_B <- function(...){ 
           obj <- new("B", ...)
           obj@a = "hello"
           obj
         }
```

and then create my object based on the prototype with `new_B()`, but that's terribly crude and ugly compared to using the generic generator `new("B")` and having my prototype...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to name the argument:

```
setClass("A", representation(a="character"))
setClass("B", contains="A", prototype=prototype(a="hello"))
```

Comment: Also, and not really part of the question, `.A <- setClass("A", representation(a="character"))` allows `.A()` or `.A(a="foo")` as constructors, rather than `new("A")`. I use `.A <- ...` rather than `A <- ...` because I still think one often will write a more formal constructor with named arguments, etc. that invokes `.A()` as its final line.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks, nice trick!  It might be useful to see an example of your more formal constructor using `.A()`, not sure why you prefer that to `new("A")`?.

Answer (score 5):

Supplementing my comment rather providing a new answer to the question, here's a solution where we still match arguments by position (because we specify additional representation for class B):

```
.A <- setClass("A", representation(a="character"))
.B <- setClass("B", representation(b="numeric"),
     prototype(a="hello"),
     contains="A")
```

`.A()` and `.B()` replace calls  to `new("A")` and `new("B")`. At some level this is syntactic sugar, but can make object construction more transparent

```
## construct an object using B's prototype, like new("B", b=1:3)
> .B(b=1:3)
An object of class "B"
Slot "b":
[1] 1 2 3

Slot "a":
[1] "hello"

## construct an object using A's prototype, like new("B", new("A"), b=1:3)
> .B(.A(), b=1:3)
An object of class "B"
Slot "b":
[1] 1 2 3

Slot "a":
character(0)
```

(the second example uses the fact that unnamed arguments to `new` or `B` are used to initialize inherited classes).

It isn't so friendly for the user to have to use `.A` or `.B` directly, e.g., because the signature is just `...` and so would be documented as 'see the definition of slots for class A'. This disrupts the separation of interface and implementation that is a strength of OOP. Also, one or the other behavior in the last code chunk (`.B(.A(a=a), b=b)` or `.B(a=a, b=b)`) might not be the intention. So instead provide a function that *is* exposed to the user, perhaps doing some initial data massage

```
A <- function(a=character(), ...) {
    ## nothing special, just a public constructor
    .A(a=a, ...)
}

B <- function(b, a="hello", ...) {
    a <- tolower(a)  ## no SHOUTing!
    .B(A(a=a), b=b)  ## A's public interface; no need for B to know A's details
}
```

The functions A and B define the interface, provide the user with hints about what acceptable arguments are without tying the constructor to the class definition, and perform preliminary data massaging. The latter can make `initialize` methods unnecessary, which is a good thing because these have a [complicated contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247583/inheritance-in-r/16248773#16248773) (they're supposed to initialize *and* be copy constructors, and as we've seen above unnamed arguments are supposed to initialize base classes) that most people get wrong.

Mostly these are just my opinions.