# R cannot declare setClass with inheritance

Tags: r, inheritance, initialization, r-s4

```
removeClass("A")
setClass('A',representation=representation(a="numeric"))

setMethod('initialize','A', function(.Object,...,a){

.Object@a=a
.Object
})
```

ok up to here

```
removeClass("B")

setClass('B',representation=representation(b="numeric"),contains="A")
```

This code fails on the definition of class "B" , without I had any chance to add an initialize method for "B", and without I even create any object

**Error in .local(.Object, ...) : argument "a" is missing, with no default**

It does not fail if I add a default value for the a parameter in initialize.A method

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: Isn't "It does not fail if I add a default value for the a parameter in initialize.A method" the solution? Maybe you want to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197214/how-to-define-an-s4-prototype-for-inherited-slots

Comment: the strange thing is merely adding the line setClass... without even creating an object triggers the error. And suppose I am reusing code that I subclass, I am not going to modify it

Answer (score 1):

"why" is a tricky question, with the answer being "because" it's implemented that way. If you're asking what needs to be done to avoid this, the answer is to either (a) provide a default value to the argument `a` in the constructor or (b) avoid using an initialize method. There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247583/inheritance-in-r/16248773#16248773). The implicit contract is that `new("A")` succeeds,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Having read the discussion, looks like it's best to simply avoid initialize methods with inheritance