# Extending original error messages

Tags: r, error-handling, reference-class

Is there a way to **directly** extend/augment/overwrite the **original** error messages that are thrown when calls to functions that I didn't write myself fail (i.e. functions from *base R* and *contributed packages*)?

### Example

Consider the following Reference Class:

```
setRefClass("A", fields=list(x1="character"))
```

No error when specifying correct values:

```
new("A", x1="Hello World!")
```

Resulting error when specifying wrong values:

```
> new("A", x1=TRUE)
Error: invalid assignment for reference class field 'x1', should be from class "character" or a subclass (was class "logical")
```

Now, I'd like to include information about the class that actually "caused the problem".

Maybe this could look something like this:

```
Error: Field assignment error in class 'A':
Invalid assignment for reference class field 'x1', should be from class "character" or a subclass (was class "logical")
```

My current workarounds for realizing something close often look like this:

```
setRefClass("A", 
    fields=list(x1="character"),
    methods=list(
        setField=function(field, value) {
            tryCatch(
                .self$field(name=field, value=value),
                warning=function(cond) {
                    message(cond)
                    .self$field(field=field, value=value)    
                },
                error=function(cond) {
                    stop(paste0("Field assignment error in class '", 
                        class(.self), "'\n"), 
                        "ORIGINAL ERROR:\n", as.character(cond)
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
)
```

After instantiating a "blank" object first

```
x <- new("A")
```

this would give me the following error when trying to set wrong values to the field via the explicit setter method:

```
> x$setField(field="x1", value=TRUE)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Field assignment error in class 'A'
ORIGINAL ERROR:
Error: invalid assignment for reference class field 'x1', should be from class "character" or a subclass (was class "logical")
```

**I don't like it for the following reasons:**

1. It's a lot of code for just a little extra information and the `tryCatch()` part makes the code somewhat harder to read.
2. Due to the nature of `tryCatch()`, AFAIU I'm obliged to also put the `.self$field(field=field, value=value)` statement within the `warning()` function if I expect somewhat "regular" behavior (i.e. "even though there was a warning, the field value is still set"). That's duplicated code.
3. Seems to me that coercing error messages via `as.character()` (AFAIU necessary in order to being able to add information via `paste()` or the like) sometimes cuts the error message off.
4. That way I'm forced to set my field values via explicit setter functions (`<obj>$setField(<field>, <value>)`) as opposed to setting them via the "built-in" `initialize` function (`new("A", <field>=<value>)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It turns out to be useful to write a proper constructor that does useful things, including communicating to the user expected argument types, providing appropriate default values, and checking / coercing argument values

   ```
   .A <- setRefClass("A", fields=list(x1="character"))

   A <- function(x1=character(), ...) {
       if (!is.character(x1))
           stop("field 'x1' should be character()")
       .A(x1=x1, ...)
   }
   ```
2. Warnings are more usually handled using `withCallingHandler` and invoking a restart

   ```
   withCallingHandlers({
       warning("oops")
       1
   }, warning=function(warn) {
       warning("I'm handling: ", conditionMessage(warn), call.=FALSE)
       invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
   })
   ```

   with output

   ```
   [1] 1
   Warning message:
   I'm handling: oops
   ```

   Use a `withCallingHandlers(tryCatch())` paradigm to handle both warnings (with restarts) and errors.
3. Access the condition message with `conditionMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. One follow-up question: what do you think of putting the checks in an `initialize` method of class `A` (`methods=list(initialize=function(x1, ...) {<if-else> return(callSuper(x1=x1, ...))})`) instead of an "outside" function `A`? What are the pros and cons of the two approaches?

Comment: @Rappster initialize methods are tricky -- they function as a copy constructor, and the implicit contract is that `.A$new()` works. For this reason it often makes sense _not_ to mess with the defaults. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247583/inheritance-in-r/16248773#16248773)